# Tensorflow dynamic_rnn TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to get a basic LSTM working in TensorFlow. I'm receiving the following error:

`TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.`

The offending line is:

```
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, sequence_length=seqlen,
                                            initial_state=init_state,)`
```

I'm using version 1.0.1 on windows 7. My inputs and label have the following shapes

`x_shape = (50, 40, 18),  y_shape = (50, 40)`

Where:

- batch size = 50
- sequence length = 40
- input vector length at each step = 18

I'm building my graph as follows

```
def build_graph(learn_rate, seq_len, state_size=32, batch_size=5):

    # use a fixed sequence length
    seqlen = tf.constant(seq_len, shape=[batch_size],dtype=tf.int32)

    # Placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, 18])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None])
    keep_prob = tf.constant(1.0)

    # RNN
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(state_size)
    init_state = tf.get_variable('init_state', [1, state_size],
                                initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    init_state = tf.tile(init_state, [batch_size, 1])
    rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, sequence_length=seqlen,
                                                initial_state=init_state,)

    # Add dropout, as the model otherwise quickly overfits
    rnn_outputs = tf.nn.dropout(rnn_outputs, keep_prob)

    # Prediction layer
    with tf.variable_scope('prediction'):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    preds = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(rnn_outputs, W) + b)

    # MSE
    loss = tf.square(tf.subtract(y, preds))

    # loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(loss)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence length should be iterable e.g. a list or tensor, not a scalar. In your case specifically, you need to replace `sequence length = 40` with a list of the lengths of each input. For instance, if your first sequence has 10 steps, the second 13 and the third 18, you would pass in `[10, 13, 18]`. This lets TensorFlow's dynamic RNN know how many steps to unroll for (I believe it uses a while loop internally).